# How to replace the default "Add Document" link with "Add New Folder" in a library

Tags: document-library

I want to replace the "Add Document" link at the bottom of a document library, with an "Add New Folder" link, any ideas please?

Comment: check this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3add1f30-0a03-40a2-9417-2ed9de893004/how-can-i-change-the-text-of-add-document-link-in-sharepoint-2010-document-library?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious